# OOP style JS not working with setInterval function

Tags: javascript, oop

From what I have gathered from other posts it looks like it is not possible, but why can't i call a setInterval function (slightly shorter hand) like this?

```
tick: function() {
     var self = this;
     setInterval(this.calculateTime, 1000);
 }
```

I need to use the following.

```
  tick: function() {
    var self = this;
    setInterval(function(){this.calculateTime()}, 1000);
  }
```

Can anyone explain why this is the case and put my mind at ease?

**Please see complete code below**

```
var countdownTimer = {

  init: function(end) {
    this.endTime = new Date(end);
  },

  calculateTime: function(){
    this.now = new Date();
    this.difference = this.endTime - this.now;
    this.seconds = Math.floor(this.difference / 1000);
    this.minutes = Math.floor(this.seconds / 60);
    this.hours = Math.floor(this.minutes / 60);
    this.days = Math.floor(this.hours / 24);
    this.hours %= 24;
    this.minutes %= 60;
    this.seconds %= 60;
  },

  tick: function() {
    var self = this;
    setInterval(function(){this.calculateTime()}, 1000);
  }
}

countdownTimer.init('02/09/2016');
countdownTimer.calculateTime();
countdownTimer.tick();
```

Comment: There are dozens of versions of this question on SO, starting with those about those about how `this` works, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work).

Comment: @torazaburo i understood `this` referred to the `window`, it was that i had to  use `bind(this)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bind` for your purpose:

```
setInterval(this.calculateTime.bind(this), 1000);
```

Comment: thats the one Christoph, good knowledge! Will give you the green tick when I can

Comment: He didn't ask how to do it. He asked WHY HE NEEDS TO DO IT.

Comment: @torazaburo i was very satisfied with how the question was answered

Comment: Your very own question stated explicitly, *Can anyone **explain** why this is the case*. Anyway, with the advent of arrow functions, the cool boys would write this as `setInterval(() => this.calculateTime(), 1000);`.

Comment: @torazaburo i wouldn't know, I'm not a cool boy! :-) an explanation was what i was looking for, but a solution is even better. perhaps i phrased the question badly! Anyway, I'm really happy with the answer! thanks for your feedback, appreciate it